# pythonanywhere + flask: website just says 'unhandled exception'. How to get debugger to print stack trace?

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

Be forewarned of a triple-newbie threat - new to python, new to [python anywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), new to flask.

[pythonanywhere-root]/mysite/test01.py

```
# A very simple Flask Hello World app for you to get started with...

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template # for templating
#from flask import request   # for handling requests eg form post, etc

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True #bshark: turn on debugging, hopefully?

@app.route('/')
#def hello_world():
#    return 'Hello from Flask! wheee!!'
def buildOrg():
    orgname = 'ACME Inc'
    return render_template('index.html', orgname)
```

And then in [pythonanywhere-root]/templates/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>Test01 App</title></head>
<body>
{% if orgname %}
  <h1>Welcome to {{ orgname }} Projects!</h1>
{% else %}
<p>Aw, the orgname wasn't passed in successfully :-(</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit up the site, I get 'Unhandled Exception' :-(
How do I get the debugger to at least spit out where I should start looking for the problem?

Comment: Look at the error logs under "Web" tab.

Comment: omg... thx! It says 'TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'.. is it that thing where a class method expects the first arg to be self? hrm...

Comment: also, I would like to accept your comment as the answer as I can see all the python errors in there. IF you restate it as an answer I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template) only expects one positional argument, and rest of the arguments are passed as keyword only arguments.So, you need to change your code to:

```
def buildOrg():
    orgname = 'ACME Inc'
    return render_template('index.html', name=orgname)
```

For the first part, you can find the error logs under the `Web` tab on pythonanywhere.com.

Comment: accepting due to pointing me at error logs. However the fix for render_template does not work (see my response to Omid Raha)...

Comment: @user3465444 Did you fix this mistake at other places as well? (And don't forget to reload the application after making changes)

Comment: Hi... orgname=orgname param worked after all; the issue is that my templates folder was not in the right place. Once I moved it, everything worked. Yay! thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also pass your name of `orgname` variable that is used in your template to `render_template`.

[flask.render_template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template):

```
 flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context)

    Renders a template from the template folder with the given context.
    Parameters: 
      template_name_or_list – the name of the template to be rendered, 
      or an iterable with template names the first one existing will be rendered
      context – the variables that should be available in the context of the template.
```

So, change this line:

```
return render_template('index.html', orgname)
```

To:

```
return render_template('index.html', orgname=orgname)
```

Comment: Thanks Omid. It didn't work:2014-03-26 19:08:40,801 :    return render_template('index.html', orgname=orgname)
2014-03-26 19:08:40,801 :TypeError: render_template() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Hi again Omid - turns out you were right!! my templates folder was simply in the wrong place - I had mis-read the Flask quickstart guide. Once it was in the right place, the second param set to orgname=orgname worked perfectly. Thank you!